# Targeting the @media section of stylesheet with JS

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a basic responsive menu that, when the screen size is 600px or less, becomes an expandable side menu. I wrote these two basic JS functions to control it:

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById('nav-right').style.width = '100%';
document.getElementById('nav-main').style.display = 'flex';
document.getElementById('menu-btn').style.display = 'none'};
```

and

```
function closeNav() {
document.getElementById('nav-right').style.width = '0';
document.getElementById('nav-main').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('menu-btn').style.display = 'block';}
```

The problem is that, once these functions are activated, these styles carry over when the screen size is increased again. Is there a way to make these disappear once the screen size is over 600px? Total newbie here, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: don't set inline styles, toggle one class (like `menu-open` ) and based on this class you set your styles, together with mediaqueries.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I thought toggle was just for jQuery. This helped a lot.

Comment: btw, jquery is just javascript, so everything that jquery can do can also be done with javascript.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need javascript here.

```
.nav-right{width:0}
.nav-main{display:none}
.menu-btn{display:block}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-right{width:100%}
  .nav-main{display:block}
  .menu-btn{display:none}
}
```